# two consecutive fwrites on same file

Tags: c, file, fwrite

i have read all sources and I tried to understand why this code is giving such output, but i couldn't understand. Please if someone could give me specific answers....

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
    FILE *fp1;
    FILE *fp2;

    fp1=fopen("abc","w");
    fp2=fopen("abc","w");

    fwrite("BASIC",1,5,fp1);
    fwrite("BBBBB CONCEPTS",1,14,fp2);

    return 0;
}
```

The output is BASIC CONCEPTS when i opened the file "abc". 
Why has second fwrite  not overwritten the contents of file "abc"?
the expected output should be BBBBB CONCEPTS

Comment: Try adding various combinations of (the missing calls to) `fclose()`  to the code an see what happens.

Comment: Which compiler are you using?  MSVC generates the output you expect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is, that you are using the buffered `fwrite()` instead of the unbuffered `write()`. The later tells the kernel: "write this stuff to the file *now*", the first tells the standard C library "write this stuff to the file whenever you see fit". Obviously, that standard C library implementation has flushed the stuff from `fp2` first, then overwriting it with the stuff from `fp1`.

Of course, you can enforce the correct flushing sequence by calling `fflush()` yourself, and/or actually closing your files.

Comment: The more interesting question to me is why is this particular order used when flushing the content.

Comment: @GearoidMurphy That particular order will be implementation dependent, afaik there is absolutely no guarantee on this in the C standard. It essentially boils down to the question whether a loop in the cleanup code works from front to back or from back to front, and that entirely depends on the programmer...

Answer (score 1):

As cmaster stated, `fopen` creates a buffered file stream. Buffered streams will only flush their data when explicitly told to do so via `fflush` or when the buffer is full, typically at around 4096 bytes. The small amounts of data you've written to buffered streams will not result in the data being flushed to disk.

If the program [terminates](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Closing-Streams.html#Closing-Streams) when there are still buffered streams open, libc (which implements the buffered stream) [automatically](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/program/atexit) flushes the streams, starting from the most recently opened stream, in GNU LibC anyway. As cmaster correctly points out, the order in which the files are closed is not specified by the C standard, only that they [must](http://cs.nyu.edu/courses/spring13/CSCI-GA.2110-001/downloads/C99.pdf) be closed.